# udev rule with bInterfaceNumber doesn't work

Tags: linux, usb, udev, usbserial

I'm trying to use udev to give relevant names a USB-serial device but I'm having now luck.

```
    # lsusb -d 04e2:1412 -v

    Bus 004 Device 028: ID 04e2:1412 Exar Corp. 
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
      bDeviceSubClass         2 Common Class
      bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x04e2 Exar Corp.
      idProduct          0x1412 
      bcdDevice            0.02
      iManufacturer           0 
      iProduct                0 
      iSerial                 0 
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength          141
        bNumInterfaces          4
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xa0
          (Bus Powered)
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower               94mA
        Interface Association:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        11
          bFirstInterface         0
          bInterfaceCount         2
          bFunctionClass          2 Communications
          bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
          bFunctionProtocol       0 None
          iFunction               0 
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
          bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
          bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
          iInterface              0 
          CDC Header:
            bcdCDC               1.10
          CDC ACM:
            bmCapabilities       0x06
              sends break
              line coding and serial state
          CDC Union:
            bMasterInterface        0
            bSlaveInterface         1 
          CDC Call Management:
            bmCapabilities       0x01
              call management
            bDataInterface          1
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               2
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        1
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               0
        Interface Association:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        11
          bFirstInterface         2
          bInterfaceCount         2
          bFunctionClass          2 Communications
          bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
          bFunctionProtocol       0 None
          iFunction               0 
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        2
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
          bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
          bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
          iInterface              0 
          CDC Header:
            bcdCDC               1.10
          CDC ACM:
            bmCapabilities       0x06
              sends break
              line coding and serial state
          CDC Union:
            bMasterInterface        2
            bSlaveInterface         3 
          CDC Call Management:
            bmCapabilities       0x01
              call management
            bDataInterface          3
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x86  EP 6 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               2
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        3
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
            bInterval               0
    Device Status:     0x0000
      (Bus Powered)
```

The udev rules I'm trying are:

```
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1412",  ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="test_USB0"
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1412",  ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="test_USB1"
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="02", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1412",  ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="test_USB2"
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1412",  ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="test_USB3"
```

When I use only the first udev rule without the bInterfaceNumber attribute, like so:

```
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1412",  ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="test_USB0"
```

It works ok. I can see symbolic link /dev/test_USB0 created which points to /dev/ttyUSB0 but what about the other ttyUSB devices created when I plug in this usbserial device?

My guess is to use the bInterfaceNumber attribute but when I put that in, nothing happens and it seems to completely bypass my rule.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 14):

It could be that the **interface** device with "usb" subsystem doesn't get any
device file created, only the usb device itself. You can see the udev events
created, along with variables, as you plug in your device using `udevadm
monitor`.

I see that the event for the device corresponding to the sysfs node, which can
have `bInterfaceNumber` attribute doesn't have the DEVNAME variable, which
probably signifies that there is no device file. The same sysfs node
doesn't have the "dev" file as well, which reinforces this.

Then, I think you don't want to create a symlink to a bare "usb" device, but
rather to a "tty" device, so you should match for "tty" subsystem instead.

I was able to match my single-interface tty converter with this rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", \
    ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="067b", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="2303", \
    ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00", SYMLINK+="test_USB0"
```

But then the "ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM" is getting assigned by udev rules on my
system (Debian Jessie) and yours, however unlikely, might not have them.
Still, you should be able to craft such a rule, probably by matching the usb
interface device first and assigning the bInterfaceNumber to an environment
variable and then using it in a rule matching the tty device.

Comment: ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM} works for me on Fedora 18. ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber} doesn't.

Comment: My system set `ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}` in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-serial.rules` using stanza `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"`, so udev rule files using that variable must run after that.

Comment: That's it @schlimmchen! Now works like a charm with one rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/20_FTDI_Serial.rules` reading the interface number (`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"`) and another rule `/etc/udev/rules.d/21_FTDI_Devices.rules` with `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", ATTRS{serial}=="FT5NRNN2", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00", SYMLINK+="ttyDEVICE0"` and `..., ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="01", SYMLINK+="ttyDEVICE1` respectively